# Go back to MainActivity from any activities with Flag

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-task

I want to go back to MainActivity from any activities.
For ex, my stack of activities:
**A - B - C - D.** 
A (MainActivity) is in the bottom and D is in the top of stack .

When I use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` . I can go back to A at any actvities as I expected.

But when I use flag **`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`** (without launchMode="singleTask"), it does not work as expected, it open a new Activity. 
And stacks are: 
**A - B - C - D - A**
not as document wrote:

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>   Start the activity in a new task. If a task is
>   already running for the activity you are now starting, that task is
>   brought to the foreground with its last state restored and the
>   activity receives the new intent in onNewIntent().
>
> This produces the same behavior as the "singleTask" launchMode value, discussed in the
>   previous section.

Anyone knows the reason? Thanks.

Comment: See my answer you don't need the singleTask,newTask etc.Just put this code and its done.

Comment: Sorry It 's not the answer. Because I want to know `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` does not work as document said.

Comment: I think you should use broadcast receiver for this

Comment: Thanks, `singleTask` works as I expected. I used to use broadcast receiver, I 's a solution, but I has a lot of Activities in the stack, need to listen a lot. So `singleTask` is the good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this solution solve your problem::- Only set this to `Intent`

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try but not work as I expected.

Comment: Thanks very much, I still works with `intentToLaunch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`. With 2 flags, it works like `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` (but this flags not work as expected)

Comment: Yes, you r right. Sometimes, flag is not work as per name or use or description. But, experience will teach how they works and solve problem.

Answer (score 1):

Find the solution :

Note : It will clear all previous activity and will lauch HomeActivity

```
Intent homeActivity = new Intent(context, DJ_HomeActivity.class);
homeActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
context.startActivity(homeActivity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in one.You can add and remove activity from stack like this.

```
// Add activity
public static void addActivities(String actName, Activity _activity) {
    if (Config.screenStack == null)
        Config.screenStack = new HashMap<String, Activity>();
    if (_activity != null)
        Config.screenStack.put(actName, _activity);
}

// Remove Activity
public static void removeActivity(String key) {
    if (Config.screenStack != null && Config.screenStack.size() > 0) {
        Activity _activity = Config.screenStack.get(key);
        if (_activity != null) {
            _activity.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

User add activities before setContentView to add into the stack.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addActivities("DemoActivity", DemoActivity.this)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_feed_post);
}
```

For remove activity you just call the removeActivity() and pass the key which you use when add the activity.

Comment: Sorry but it 's not the answer I want. The answer from you  answer `How to remove a particular activity from android back stack?` But with your answser, using HashMap to store stack, cannot remove activity like this : A-B-C-D-C-D. If I want to remove C in the stack, cannot. Because youf HashMap cannot store 2 C activties in Stack

Comment: You can store all your activity in this method.For e.g If you go from A-B-C-D-E-F now from F you want to go to activity A then onBackPress you just call removeActivity("Your E activity"), removeActivity("Your D activity") upto B activity and then call finish() the current activity.And that's it you are done.

Comment: Cannot with your codes above. For ex: with stack  A-B-C-D-C-D, your codes using `HashMap` cannot store stack like stack  A-B-C-D-C-D, 2 C activities in the stack

Comment: From your case you written something like this A - B - C - D - A right. So it is very simple.
1)When you come to A add your activity, When B add your activity and so on. When you Call activity A from D you just call removeActivity("Your A activity") so from this way your activity now create new A activity and you have single stack for activity A.

Answer (score 0):

Override `onBackpress` method of each activity :

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I know  `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` It will clear all activities in the task and open new Activities, not go back to the Activities in the stack

Answer (score -1):

you should use below code to jump on the MainActivity.With the `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` following flag of intent it clears the all previous activity.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Note one thing, You used `android:launchMode="singleTask"`So while moving from **A** activity to another activity you must have to finish **A** Activity by using `this.finish()` method.