# How to manipulate back stack using FLAG and Activity Affinity

Tags: android, android-intent, back-stack

I have gone through android docs on FLAGS and Affinity ([Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK))
and tried different combinations that I thought would help achieve my requirement but it seems that I'm missing something.

I need to initiate `activityA` from from `BroadcastReceiver` and then finish `activityA` and start `activityB`. so when the user presses back it wont go back to `activityA`; when user `presses back` on `activityB` it will stop the `activityB` and it will go to `back stack` however when the user opens app back from `task manager` it will start up from `activityA`.

**Note:** this does not happen when there is another activity of the app in the background.(only happens when the app is entirely force closed/killed).
also when user presses `home button` in `activityB` it behaves as intended.

I use the following code to lunch `activityA` from `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityA.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TAG, new Gson().toJson(remoteMessage));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

I use the following code to lunch `activityB` from `ActivityA`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Is there a different `FLAG` that I need to use to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Just try this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43625394/7806873